# Angular Use same TemplateRef in more than one place at a time - Clone TemplateRef?

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to build a multi-select component which can take a template for each select option element. It's mostly working, the templates are grabbed from the ng-content in the option component and displays in the "select popover" fine.

[image: Options display fine]

I'm having issues when trying to display the selected option in the select component. It seems that the template can only be shown in one place at a time, so when the selected option is displayed in the select, it is removed from the popover.

[image: Options display wrong]

Is there any way I could clone the TemplateRef component? I don't actually mind if the context doesn't update for the template as I'm not currently using anything from it, just the template.

Including some code snips below for clarity, I think it's okay though.

**Usage in `somepage.component.html`:**

```
<my-select [(value)]="vals">
    <my-option *ngFor="let x of [1,2,3]" [value]="x">Option {{x}}</my-option>
</my-select>`
```

**my-select.component.html**

```
...
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="getSelectedOptionTemplate()"></ng-container>
...
```

**my-select.component.ts**

```
getSelectedOptionTemplate(){
    // Some way to clone here could solve the issue?
    return this.getSelectedOption().template;
}
```

**my-select-overlay.component.html**

```
...
<ng-container *ngFor="let opt of options;">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="getTemplate(opt)"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
...
```

**my-option.component.html**

```
<ng-template>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

**my-option.component.ts**

```
...
@ViewChild(TemplateRef)
template: TemplateRef<any>;
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I've found on [Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37995) a solution for this issue.

It seems that using the same `TemplateRef` works when the `ng-template` **is wrapping the component** that contains the `ng-content`.

Imagine that we need to obtain something like:

```html
<ng-template>
   <my-option>
      ... option content ...(<ng-content></ng-content>)
   </my-option>
</ng-template>`
```

In order to obtain the structure above, we can implement a [structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives). From the docs:

> Angular transforms the asterisk in front of a structural directive
> into an `<ng-template>` that surrounds the host element and its
> descendants.

The code for the structural directive would be:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: "[appOptionTemplate]"
})
export class OptionTemplateDirective {
  @Input("appOptionTemplate")
  value: any;

  constructor(
    public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>
  ) {}
}
```

(note the following:

- the injection of the `templateRef` in the constructor
- the `Input` property)

When populating the select options, we'll use the following:

```html
<app-select>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let x of [1,2,3]; let i=index;">
    <app-option *appOptionTemplate="x">
      Option {{x}}
    </app-option>
  </ng-container>
</app-select>
```

Now, we'll use the structural directive for querying the content in the `select` component:

```ts
@ContentChildren(OptionTemplateDirective)
options: QueryList<OptionTemplateDirective>;
```

And for displaying the option, we'll use:

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="option.templateRef"></ng-container>
```

**Example:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pues8t

---

**Github** topic:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37995

---

More info about structural directives:

https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives